# Trying to modify the URL that gets displayed in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Hi iam using the following ga code to modify the url that get displayed in google analytics but it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-22140531-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-22140531-1");
pageTracker._trackPageview("change_password");

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + 
    '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

When i see the top content on my google analytics code the url of page accessed get displayed but i want that the name which i used in pageTracker._trackPageview() method should get displayed.
The above code does not work for me.What is the problem in the above code?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the asynchronous version of the tracking code and then trying to get a `pageTracker` from the `_gat` object. However, this won't exist at the point in time that it runs as the `ga.js` script hasn't loaded. This is why the asynchronous code uses an object called the `_gaq`. This is a queue of operations that are to be performed when `ga.js` has finished loading. You need to add your tracking calls to it as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'change_password']);


  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + 
    '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

You can see from this that the original `pageTracker._trackPageview("change_password");` call has changed to `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'change_password']);`. You put the method name you want to call as the first element of the array and the arguments go in subsequent sections.

Note: I've changed the account number to `UA-XXXXXXXX-X` so it's not publicly visible. You need to change it back to the original.

You can learn more about using the asynchronous tracking code at: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html

Comment: is correct. **_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'change_password'])** is the correct syntax for the async tracker. **pageTracker._trackPageview** is the syntax for the old tracker.